# Why the request is being save in express?

Tags: node.js, email, express, mandrill

I have a problem.
I am developing an API with Node and the express framework to send transactional email using Mandril.
I download the [powerdrill](https://github.com/rschmukler/powerdrill) library to call the Mandrill API.

Everything is working fine, the emails are being sent ok, except for the problem that the request in the post is saving.

For example, if I call the API once I will send one email, and if I send a  second one I will send 2 emails (the first one that I sent and the new one), and if I call the API once again I will send 3 email (the first 2 and the new one).

[image]
[image]

As you can see I sent 1 email using the request welcome. In the second one I called other request called submittedApplication but when I call the API using POSTMAN 2 emails were sent 1.-the new one and 2.- the first one again.

Does anyone know why the request is saving?

```
var express = require('express'),
router = express.Router(),
config = require('config'),
Message = require('powerdrill').Message;
var message = new Message();

router.get('/',function(req,res){
res.send('test ok Mandrillllll');
})

router.post('/welcomeGorn',function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body);
  message.apiKey(config.mandrillKey)
    .subject(req.body.subject)
    .template(req.body.template)
    .from(config.mandrilEmail)
    .to(req.body.to)
    .tag('complex')
    .globalMergeVar('VERIFY_EMAIL',req.body.linkVefifyEmail)
    .send(function(err, resp) {
      //console.log(resp);
      res.send(resp).end();
    });
});

router.post('/submittedApplication',function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body);
  message.apiKey(config.mandrillKey)
    .subject(req.body.subject)
    .template(req.body.template)
    .from(config.mandrilEmail)
    .to(req.body.to)
    .tag('complex')
    .globalMergeVar('RECRUITER_NAME',req.body.recruiterName)
    .globalMergeVar('RECRUITER_EXTENSION',req.body.recruiterExtension)
    .globalMergeVar('RECRUITER_EMAIL',req.body.recruiterEmail)
    .send(function(err, resp) {
      //console.log(resp);
      res.send(resp);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The console is showing me this warning:
**Powerdrill: Attempting to add the same email twice. Using data from first instance**

You can find this warning [here](https://github.com/rschmukler/powerdrill/blob/master/lib/message.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is message variable is saving all information and sending all together every time. Try to initialize it at the beginning of every method:

```
router.post('/welcomeGorn',function(req,res){
    var message = new Message();
```